# Bootstrap Typeahead not showing hint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using Bootstrap Typeahead with a custom JSON response and custom rendering with templates. The problem is the "hint" is not showing anymore, because of the custom rendering of the result. Is there a way to specify the "hint"-key (in my case "keyword") of the JSON dictionary result?

By removing "templates" the hint is working of course, but I need custom rendering.

```
var query = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('keyword'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: '/autocomplete?q=%QUERY'
});

$('#idSearch').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    name: 'query',
    source: query,
    templates: {
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{keyword}}</p>')
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108237/bootstrap-tag-typeahead-input-not-populating-menu-with-jquery-ajax/43375406#43375406

Answer (score 0):

in typeahead.js  _updateHint: all the magic happens: I changed

```
match = frontMatchRegEx.exec(datum.value);
```

to

```
match = frontMatchRegEx.exec(datum.raw.keyword);
```

and it's working with custom templates.